# Import for getHourOfDay scala

Tags: scala

I have a scala function to test the hours of the day, I used the method `getHourOfDay` and I added the concerned import, but still display an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have been `getHour` instead of `getHourOfDay`

```
var myhour = d1.getHour()
var myminute = d1.getMinute()
```